# Simple HTML / CSS Question (Forms / Selector)

Tags: html, css

I'm working my way though a beginners HTML and CSS tutorial and I'm unable to get my "T Shirt Size" selector to be on the same line with the selection.

I really would like someone to help me with this.  I need to be able to get the tshirt size selector on the same line as my the dropdown list when in full-screen so that it looks good!

Here is the outcome that I'm looking for: [image: WANTED OUTCOME]

Here is the outcome I'm getting:
[image: Outcome I'm getting.]

Here is my CSS Code:

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: #5D6063;
  background-color: #EAEDF0;
  font-family: "Helvecta", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.3;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.speaker-form-header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F6F7F8;
  border: 1px solid #D6D9DC;
  border-radius: 3px;

  width: 80%;
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 50px;
}

.speaker-form-header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.speaker-form {
  background-color: #F6F7F8;
  border: 1px solid #D6D9DC;
  border-radius: 3px;

  width: 80%;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

.form-row {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-row input[type='text'],
.form-row input[type='email']{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D6D9DC;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form-row label {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .speaker-form-header,
  .speaker-form {
    width: 600px;
  }
  .form-row {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start; /* To avoid stretching */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .form-row input[type='text'],
  .form-row input[type='email'],
  .form-row select,
  .form-row textarea {
    width: 250px;
    height: initial;

  }
  .form-row label {
    text-align: right;
    width: 120px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }

  .legacy-form-row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .legacy-form-row legend {
    width: 120px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }

  .legacy-form-row legend {
    float: left;
  }
}

.form-row input[type='text']:invalid,
.form-row input[type='email']:invalid {
  border: 1px solid #D55C5F;
  color: #D55C5F;
  box-shadow: none; /* Remove default red glow in Firefox */
}

.legacy-form-row {
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.legacy-form-row legend {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.legacy-form-row .radio-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
}

.legacy-form-row input[type='radio'] {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.legacy-form-row .radio-label,
.legacy-form-row input[type='radio'] {
  float: left;
}

.form-row select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
}
```

and html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>Speaker Submission</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class='speaker-form-header'>


      <h1>Speaker Submission</h1>
      <p><em>Want to speak at our fake conference? Fill out this form!</em></p>

    </header>

      <form action='' method='get' class='speaker-form'>
        <div class='form-row'>
          <label for='full-name'>Name</label>
          <input id='full-name' name='full-name' type='text'/>
        </div>

          <div class='form-row'>
            <label for='email'>Email</label>
            <input id='email'
                   name='email'
                   type='email'
                   placeholder='joe@example.com'/>
          </div>

          <fieldset class='legacy-form-row'>
            <legend>Type of Talk</legend>
            <input id='talk-type-1'
                   name='talk-type'
                   type='radio'
                   value='main-stage' />
            <label for='talk-type1' class='radio-label'>Main Stage</label>

            <input id='talk-type-2'
                   name='talk-type'
                   type='radio'
                   value='workshop'
                   checked />
            <label for='talk-type-2' class='radio-label'>Workshop</label>
        </fieldset>

        <div class='form-row'>
          <label for='t-shirt'>T-Shirt Size</label>
          <select id='t-shirt' name='t-shirt'>
            <option value='xs'>Extra Small</option>
            <option value='s'>Small</option>
            <option value='m'>Medium</option>
            <option value='l'>Large</option>
          </select>
        </div>


      </form>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please also include the html code in your question. Only the CSS is not enough to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Oops, there is the HTML!

Comment: You need to remove `width: 100%;` from the `.form-row select` style: https://jsfiddle.net/cr2oj1zt/1/

Answer (score 3):

Your `.form-row select` style has `width: 100%;` which makes the `select` element fill the entire width of the parent `div`. So you just need to remove that line:

```css
.form-row select {
  /* remove the following line */
  /* width: 100%; */
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cr2oj1zt/1/

Comment: I appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set width value equal 100%. It will take the space of your div container. If you don't want it to equal the div width, you must specify value for select element. For example:

```
.form-row select {
  width: 30%; /* or other value you want apply for the select element */
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
}
```